# Jenkins - How to capture environment variable from shell?

Tags: jenkins-groovy

I have a shell script in groovy

```
sh '''
test="hello"
echo $test
'''
String t = env.test;
println t;
```

i want capture the shell environment test

It's possible ?

Answer (score 0):

The way you doing, the variable is only set on the shell, Jenkins can't read it.

What you can do is to assign the stdout of your shell command to an environment variable, and use it across your pipeline.

```
env.test = sh( script: "echo test", returnStdout: true ).trim()

println test
```